# How do I send two SMS messages in a chain to the same receiver with twilio?

Tags: ruby, sms, twilio

I am working on a project that returns SMS messages to a user who has just sent a SMS message to the server.

The process is:

- The user sends a SMS message to the server.
- The server will send two SMS messages back to this user. Note that these are two separate short messages and will be sent pretty much at the same time.

I've got the sending part working, but just for sending one SMS message, not two. When I add more code to send another message only the second message part works, which means only the second message has been sent out, the first message has been ignored.

The code looks pretty much like:

```
  else
sms = SMS.create(:body => params['Body'], :from => params['From'], :to => params['To'], :created_at => Time.now)

  #return a random saved sms
    return_secret = SMS.first(:offset => rand(SMS.count))
    twiml = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
        r.Sms return_secret.body
  #send another message to remind user for rating
    ask_rating = remind_rating
   if ask_rating 
    twiml = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
      r.Sms ask_rating
    end
    twiml.text
   end
```

Does anyone know how to send two messages in Twilio?

Comment: A minor nitpick. "[SMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_Message_Service)" = "Short Message Service" which is a "service" used to send messages. So, saying you're sending "SMS" doesn't make sense. You're sending either a "SMS message", or more simply, a "message".

Comment: oh thank you for the revise Tin Man!!

Answer (score 0):

You've got some variable shadowing going on with `twiml`. As you wrote it, the second message's code is inside of the first message's block. Yet, you refer to a variable with the same name as one outside of the block. I would try flattening your code so you aren't nesting like that.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* the issue here is you're instantiating a second TwiML::Response object when you already have one, so you can just references the previous one which you assigned to `r` in the first block. You also called it `r` in the second block so you just remove the block that encloses it:

```
sms = SMS.create(:body => params['Body'], :from => params['From'], :to => params['To'], :created_at => Time.now)

#return a random saved sms
return_secret = SMS.first(:offset => rand(SMS.count))
twiml = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
  r.Sms return_secret.body
  #send another message to remind user for rating
  ask_rating = remind_rating
  if ask_rating 
    r.Sms ask_rating
  end
end
```

Also the blocks weren't balanced in the initial code snippet so I stripped out the `else` to make it syntactically accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, really appreciate your replies. 
After consulting with twilio team, they gave me an example like this:

```
require 'rubygems' 
require 'twilio-ruby' 
require 'sinatra' 

get '/sms-quickstart' do 
twiml = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r| 
r.Message "Hey Monkey. Thanks for the message!" 
r.Message "this is the 2nd message" 
end 
twiml.text 
end
```

I just deleted

```
if ask_rating 
twiml = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
```

everything works...